# Xcode / Objective C - Dynamically import files (via folder, regex, etc.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, import

I am creating an iOS framework (like an acyclic MVC) and want a Controller to be able to import all View files. The view files are all in a folder and have a `*View.h` naming.

**Is it possible to import all views in one line by doing something like `#import "/Views"` or `#import "*View.h"`? What's the simplest way to dynamically import?**

Currently I am importing a header file which contains the other header files. This works, but I would like a way to dynamically import so I can add a View and not have to update imports before using it.

Comment: What's the problem with typing out each view you want to include?

Comment: Technically, you can use modules.

Comment: Droppy - It works, but a dynamic import would mean less time setting up each time I add a class, and it provides a nice abstraction layer imo.

Comment: Andy - how could I use modules to accomplish this? I'm familiar with what they are and how to use them, but I haven't created one or know how to use it to dynamically import.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that because import is done during compile time. But you can archive the result by a script in which it generates the umbrella header contains all the `#import "*View.h"`. Add it into Build Phases before compile sources

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So the script would parse the directory to get the file names and output the umbrella header? How do you link the output file back into the project and reference it from the other files?